# ProgressBar countdown with Handlers in an Android application

Tags: java, android, time, progress-bar, handler

I first want to say I used google a lot to find a progress bar that fills itself when time passes. All results I found where either with a **thread** or with an **Asynctask**. As being new to Android, I thought it was easier to accomplish with an extra **Handler** that handles the updates of the progressbar.

However, I did not find anyone doing it my way. Does it maybe violate Android rules? For example, can I use multiple **Handlers** at the same time?

My code looks like:

```
public void restarttimebar()
{
    stoptimebar();
    for(int i=1;i<12;i++)
    {
    Message msg = timebarhandler.obtainMessage(0,i,0);
    timebarhandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, i*250);
    }

};

public void stoptimebar()
{
    timebarhandler.removeMessages(0);
    Message msg = timebarhandler.obtainMessage(0,0,0);
    timebarhandler.sendMessage(msg);
};

Handler timebarhandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.timebar);
        if (msg.arg1 == 0)
        {
            progressbar.setProgress(0);
        }
        if (msg.arg1 > 0)
        {
            progressbar.setProgress(msg.arg1*9);
        }
    }
};
```

Now one can call restarttimebar(); to (re)start the progress bar. It will fill over 3 seconds with increments at each 0.25 second. Any remarks greatly appreciated!!

**EDIT:** Also added a stoptimebar(); to just stop the progressbar. Also, the standard size of a progressbar is 100. So I just make the twelve updates times 9. It is almost 100 ;) The bar does not have to be THAT very precise in my application.

Comment: No remarks? I tested it on a real device (LG 2x Speed) and also in the emulator of Eclipse, and it works fine. Then I keep it this way :)
Can be useful for people that google this kind of thing.

(7 hours ago it was night at some places, so they maybe haven't seen this post :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my method of updating the progress bar can be seen as correct. So for anyone who googles and has the same kind of question: Use the code in the question!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the threads you create and Asynctasks (Non-UI-Threads) should not touch UI-stuff like your progressbar. If you need your task communicate with the progressbar, use Asynctask and make sure that UI related actions are done in onPostExecute(). This method will be also called by the main UI Thread.